# Setting value of DIV element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am just trying to create a chat application with jQuery and HTML so I`m using two HTML elements :

```
<div id="chat" style="height: 359px; width: 146px" > 
<p id="answer">
</p>
</div>
<input id="send" type="text" value="ارسال" style="width: 120px"/>
```

and this jQuery function :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
       //Get

    var bla = $('#send').val();
    bla = bla +  $('#answer').val();


    //Set
    $('#answer').val(bla);

    }
});
```

I tried this code with text instead of div element and it kind of worked but when I add a div element , it doesn`t work any more. 
Now I want to do two things :
1.Adding the text of #send to #answer element -not replacing it.
2.Create a empty line after each input.

Comment: did you try the answer given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/atoejgjd/).

Change `.val()` of `#answer` to `.html()`.

To get the data inside a `div` or `p`, `.html()` is used.

Here is the snippet.

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    //Get

    var bla = $('#send').val();
    bla = bla + $('#answer').html();


    //Set
    $('#answer').html(bla);

  }
});
```

```html
<div id="chat" style="height: 359px; width: 146px">
  <p id="answer">
  </p>
</div>
<input id="send" type="text" value="ارسال" style="width: 120px" />
```

Comment: Thanks.How can I add an empty line after each input?

Comment: You can add at the end of the function the following: $('#answer').append('<br><br>'); That will add two linebreaks to the end of the answer paragraph, which will result in a blank line.

Comment: What @BurningLights said is correct, but I would suggest `$('#answer').html("<p>" + bla + "</p>");` instead of `$('#answer').html(bla);`. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/atoejgjd/1/).

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. There's just a slight bug with the code, since it's trying to wrap the new content and the old inside #answer in a set of paragraph tags. Which results in an empty paragraph tag being added to the end every time a new message is added. Here's a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/30831mc1/1/. I changed the one line back to `$('#answer').html(bla);` and added the wrapping paragraph tags where bla is being combined with the already existing content in #answer: `bla = "<p>" + bla + "</p>" +  $('#answer').html();`